# (C# WPF SQL Server) Is it possible to connect to the database several times in one function?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is it possible to connect to the database several times in one function?

In if `SqlCommand` does not fill table.

Piece of code:

```
        public void region_wypelnij()
        {
        string Region = RegionTextBox.Text;
        string Kraj = ((DataRowView)KrajComboBox.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();

        String tresc = "Data source=ADAM_LAPTOP; Integrated Security=true; Database=tmargacz";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(tresc);
        SqlCommand polecenie = new SqlCommand("Select IdRegionu From Region Where Nazwa='" + Region + "'", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(polecenie);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet(); //reprezentują całą bazę danych wraz z relacjami pomiędzy tabelami
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Region");

        int licznik = ds.Tables["Region"].Rows.Count;
        MessageBox.Show(licznik.ToString());


        if (licznik > 0)
        { 
            string index = ds.Tables["Region"].Rows[0]["IdRegionu"].ToString();
            int indeks = Convert.ToInt32(index);

            String tresc2 = "Data source=ADAM_LAPTOP; Integrated Security=true; Database=tmargacz";
            SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(tresc2);
            SqlCommand polecenie2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Region VALUES ((SELECT Nazwa FROM Region WHERE IdRegionu ='" + indeks + "'), (SELECT IdKraju FROM Kraj WHERE Nazwa ='" + Kraj + "'))", conn2);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(polecenie2);
            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet(); //reprezentują całą bazę danych wraz z relacjami pomiędzy tabelami
            adapter.Fill(ds2, "Region");
        }
        else
        {
            String tresc2 = "Data source=ADAM_LAPTOP; Integrated Security=true; Database=tmargacz";
            SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(tresc2);
            SqlCommand polecenie2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Region VALUES ('" + Region + "', (SELECT IdKraju FROM Kraj WHERE Nazwa ='" + Kraj + "'))", conn2);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(polecenie2);
            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet(); //reprezentują całą bazę danych wraz z relacjami pomiędzy tabelami
            adapter.Fill(ds2, "Region");
        }
    }
```

Comment: **1** - Please code strictly in **English**. Otherwise no one will be able to understand your code. **2** Please remove all this horrible code from the `Code Behind`, and create a proper Data Access layer. **3** you're better off using an ORM. Creating SQL statements as strings in C# is an archaic concept. **4** - Learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF.

Comment: Yes, but why? You could use the same connection for the 3 request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do as many times as you like, though you can reuse a connection as well.

**But is your code a good code?** The answer is **NO**. You need to design your application properly. Move all the data access functionality in a separate layer and do all the DB work there.

```
if (true)
{
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
   {
         //your code
   }
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
   {
        //your code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect to the database as many times as you have available connections. You should be able to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many issues in your code.

First, yes, you can connect multiple times, however, you can reuse **the same** connection. You don' really need a new connection every time.

Second, please call Dispose on your command/connections, otherwise you leak resources.

Third, loading the whole table into memory just to count how many rows are there is a bad idea. Instead, execute a query which counts items:

```
 Select count(*) from ....
```